# Is it safe to use ComputedProperty?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need support for computed properties in App Engine. I downloaded the latest source release to try and implement them myself. Whilst going through code, I came across a property class that already seems to do *exactly* what I need.

```
class ComputedProperty(Property):
  """Property used for creating properties derived from other values.

  Certain attributes should never be set by users but automatically
  calculated at run-time from other values of the same entity.  These
  values are implemented as persistent properties because they provide
  useful search keys.

  ...
  """
```

The problem that it's undocumented; I can't find anything about `ComputedProperty` in the official docs.

So is `ComputedProperty` safe to use or is it buggy or/and subject to change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ComputedProperty` seems to be a "port" (for lack of a better word) of a custom property class named [`DerivedProperty` from Nick Johnson's blog](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Custom-Datastore-Properties-1-DerivedProperty).

Since Nick's blog entry shows how easy it can be to create a custom datastore `Property` class, I wouldn't worry much about `ComputedProperty`, as you can always replace it with a `Property` subclass of your own if need be.

Answer (score 3):

These have since been launched and documented, at least for the NDB API:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed